# Auto scroll bar not enabled for edit box having dynamic static text

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

I want to add static text controls dynamically on a edit box of mfc dialog-based application.
I am able to add the static text controls. But Auto vertical scroll bar is not enabled, even though I have enabled it on resource properties. For normal text it works fine. When I changed to dynamic static text it is not working

```
`` 

for (int nIndex = 0; nIndex < 3; nIndex++)
{
        CString csCurrent;
        m_edit.GetWindowTextW(csCurrent);
        CString csNew;
        csNew.Format(_T("number %d\r\n"), nIndex);
        csNew = csCurrent + csNew;
       

        // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
        CRect rect;
        m_edit.GetWindowRect(&rect);
        m_ColumFrontalText[0] = new CStatic;
        m_ColumFrontalText[0]->Create(csNew, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect(0, 0,100, 100), &m_edit, 1);
        m_ColumFrontalText[1] = new CStatic;
        m_ColumFrontalText[1]->Create(csNew, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect(0, 100 + 5,100, 200), &m_edit, 1);
        m_ColumFrontalText[2] = new CStatic;
        m_ColumFrontalText[2]->Create(csNew, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect(0, 210, 300, 300), &m_edit, 1);
`}`
```

Comment: *"Auto vertical scroll bar"* - For which window? I'm guessing that the question is asking about the controls' parent, but a [mcve] would certainly help.

Comment: Auto scroll bar is enabled for edit box and created static text dynamically, but scroll bar is not enabled

Comment: I don't know what an *"edit box"* is.

Comment: Add the styles  `WS_VSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL` to `WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE`

Comment: Setting edit control styles on a static control isn't going to end well. Here are the available [static control styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/static-control-styles).

Comment: Could you please clarify your intentions? Are you trying to create child static controls in the Edit control and scroll them with the content of that edit control? I don't think the Edit will flow its text around your static controls... Please explain the idea.

Comment: yes.. Actually I have an edit box with auto scroll enabled.  am adding static controls in the edit box dynamically based on a log file content. So the number of static controls may not be fixed. But I need to enable auto scroll for edit box to see all the static controls, even if the number exceed the viewable area of edit box.

Comment: What is an *"edit box"*? It's not a standard term used in Windows' GUI language.

Comment: It is edit control tool

Comment: You cannot create child windows into an edit control. That's not a supported scenario.